# php curl sending post data issue

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

I'm trying to get the data of a page by `curl` library. I can do it with simple link, but when I'm going to submit a form and then get the data , I can not. It returns me the default value of page, not the submitted form. Let me explain the code.

```
$url = ...
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
// I'm sending post data
$params = array(
      'madrak'=>5,
      'B1' => 'مشاهده اطلاعات'
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
// and execute...
```

The page I'm getting data is written with `asp` and the form part of that page is this:

```
<input type="submit" value="مشاهده اطلاعات" name="B1">

<select name="madrak" size="1" class="style1" id="1">
  <option value="1">زير ديپلم</option>
  <option value="5">ديپلم</option>
  <option value="6">فوق ديپلم</option>
  <option value="7">ليسانس</option>
  <option value="8">فوق ليسانس</option>
  <option value="9">دكترا</option>
  <option selected="" value="6">فوق ديپلم</option>
 </select>
```

It seems that the form is not being submitted. Because just I can get the data which is loading without form submitting. Any idea?

Comment: $info = curl_getinfo($ch); Try to print_r($info); for get result call back. Check HTTP_Code return is 200 or ...?

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn it returns me zero for `http_code`. But it returns data.

Comment: I can't believe http_code is 0 and you still got data return. It's impossible

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn Sorry, I was running it before `curl_exec()`. Yes, it returns 200.

Answer (score 1):

First I should mention that you don't have to build query string of the post data. You can pass the array.

Please try setting HTTP Headers too. Like content type, user agents and etc, the target website might check for the headers.

But the most important part is to set `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` HTTP Header.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded']);
```

Comment: No, it didn't work. I searched about `http_build_query` , I found out that I should use this, but without that function, it doesn't work.

Comment: @vahidnajafi You are sending the data the right way. Did you try setting other HTTP headers? The best way to test it is to copy all the headers that a browsers sends, then if it still does not give you the right result, you should consider enabled cookies for curl. Many websites use such measures to prevent data crawling.

Comment: Whether with or without `http_build_query` it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by **copy all the headers that a browsers sends** ?

Comment: In Google Chrome or Firefox open Developer tools and go to `network` pane. Resend the data and watch the requests that your browsers sends to the website, click on the main item that is the page, in `Headers` pane you can see what HTTP headers your browser sends to the server to request that specific page and it contains many. Copy all of them including cookie, test it and if you get the results that you want remove them one by one starting from cookie to make sure what is essential and necessary.

Comment: I found out what the problem is. That's because sending by post, can not get the data in `utf-8` mode. I searched a lot and couldn't find anything to really fix it.

Comment: Ok, I understand that. Can you var_dump the result of http_build_query so we know what's the exact result of it?

Comment: I found out a new issue :D When I get the character which is not utf-8 mode, I CAN compare it with persian characters. Considering the fact that some websites use `csrf` protection, maybe they don't let me submit the **post**.

Comment: @vahidnajafi You can always submit posts even if they're using CSRF protection techniques, you just have to be me more precise about the headers that you send. A web server cannot ever know that if you're a real browser or a robot if the headers are right.